# cannot update IIS 7 site redirect rule

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have two web applications, let's call them **foo.com** and **www.foo.com**.

The client asked me to 301 redirect all requests from **foo.com** to **www.foo.com**.

So what I did was select **foo.com** in IIS manager and in the HTTP Redirect settings, added a redirect to **www.foo.com**:

[image]

Problem is, it now redirects infinitely to **http://foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com/www.foo.com** until max URL Length has been reached and throws an error.

I went back and edited to destination to http://www.foo.com because I thought it was treating it as a relative redirect because I left off the "http://":

[image]

but it seems as though my first settings are being cached because no matter what I change the redirect destination to (a random URL, a word, etc), it always redirects endlessly to the same URL mentioned earlier. It's like it is cached inside of IIS and I don't know where or how to update the destination. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried doing an `iisreset`?

Comment: No. We're currently at peak traffic time, so unless I absolutely have to, I can't. If I can't find another solution, I'll do it after hours and see what happens.